# Размытое изображение CLion Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, clion, manjaro

установил CLion на Manjaro через pamac. Все шрифты, иконки размыты, в браузере, телеграмме и других приложениях всё норм, кроме Google Chrome. Использую Gnome, все обновления установлены. У ноутбука разрешение Quad HD.